# How to configure the following pattern in a <f:converternumber/>?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, icefaces

Good afternoon

The specific question is: the number 0 with the pattern should be applied with the following format 0000-00, the number 201201 with the pattern should be applied with the following format as 2012-01 etc

eh trying to

```
<h:inputText value="#{periodo.periodo}">
  <f:convertNumber pattern="####-####">
  </f:convertNumber>
</h:inputText>
```

but the result is the number 0: 0 -

Any help on this would be very grateful for me/

Answer (score 0):

you can use converdateTime like below

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM">
</f:convertDateTime>
```

you can define your date pattern.

Comment: This works only if `#{periodo.periodo}` is a `java.util.Date`. OP's situation however suggests that it's a `java.lang.Number` (which is at its own indeed a bad choice in first place though).